# Jetty embedded + Spring MVC + Spring security + Https

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, https, embedded-jetty

I am configuring a system with this requirements:

- Spring MVC
- Jetty 9 embedded
- Spring Security over Https

Spring Boot could be a good starting point but it is not working due to our old hardware. We need to configure Spring just with these parts.

I have a working code with Spring MVC, Jetty and Spring Security but over Http:

**Spring Security:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${web.security.http.username1}") private String webUser1;
    @Value("${web.security.http.password1}") private String webPassword1;

    private static String REALM = "MY_TEST_REALM";

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception, BadCredentialsException {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser( webUser1 ).password( webPassword1 ).roles("USER");
    }

    /**
     * Ignored resources
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
        .ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**")
        .and()
        .ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }  

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http      
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
            .csrf()        
        .and()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint())
        .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).sessionFixation().none()
        .and()
            .headers()
                .xssProtection()
            .and()
                .frameOptions()
            .and()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(60 * 60)               
            .and()
                .contentTypeOptions()
            .and()
                .contentSecurityPolicy(""
                            + "default-src 'self'; " 
                            + "script-src 'self'; "
                            + "connect-src 'self'; "
                            + "img-src 'self'; "
                            + "font-src 'self'; "
                            + "frame-ancestors 'none'; "
                            + "base-uri 'self'; "
                            + "form-action 'self'; "
                            + "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; ")
            .and()
                // internet explorer
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy","sandbox"));   
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint() {
        BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setRealmName(REALM);
        return entryPoint;
    }
}
```

**Jetty Configuration:**

```
@Bean
    public WebAppContext jettyWebAppContext() throws IOException {

        WebAppContext webUiContext = new WebAppContext();
        webUiContext.setContextPath(jettyContextPath);
        webUiContext.setWar(new ClassPathResource("webapp").getURI().toString());
        webUiContext.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "false");
        webUiContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        GenericWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
        webApplicationContext.setParent(applicationContext);
        webApplicationContext.refresh();
        webUiContext.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, webApplicationContext);
        webUiContext.addEventListener(new WebMvcContextInit());
        webUiContext.addFilter(
            new FilterHolder( new DelegatingFilterProxy( 
                    AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME ) ), 
                    "/*", EnumSet.allOf( DispatcherType.class )
        );

        return webUiContext;
    }



@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server jettyServer() throws IOException {

JettyConfigurationMapper mappedFile = readJettyAccessConfigurationMapper();
            Server server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress(jettyHost, jettyPort));
            InetAccessHandler inetAccessHandler = buildInetAccessHandler(mappedFile);
            server.setHandler(inetAccessHandler);
            inetAccessHandler.setHandler(jettyWebAppContext());
            return server;
}
```

When I change jetty configuration to https with the following code, I only see `403 Forbidden` in the browser, with any security form (http basic auth):

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server jettyServer() throws IOException {

        System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

            HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();         
            httpConfig.setSecureScheme("https");
            httpConfig.setSecurePort(jettyPort);

            HttpConfiguration httpsConfig = new HttpConfiguration(httpConfig);
            httpsConfig.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

            Resource jksFile = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:" + myKeystoreJks);
            SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
            sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(jksFile.getURL().toExternalForm());
            sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(myKeystorePassword);

            Server server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress(jettyHost, 8080));
            ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"), 
                    new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfig));
            sslConnector.setPort(jettyPort);
            server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { sslConnector });
            JettyConfigurationMapper mappedFile = readJettyAccessConfigurationMapper();
            InetAccessHandler inetAccessHandler = buildInetAccessHandler(mappedFile);
            server.setHandler(inetAccessHandler);
            inetAccessHandler.setHandler(jettyWebAppContext());

            return server;
    }
```

Comment: Ehrm why wouldn't spring boot be working?! If you can do this, Spring Boot should work as well, without you having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I agree. Honestly, we do not why. This is an extremly slow system. We customized imports even lazy-load and jetty instead tomcat but the program could take up to 40 mins to startup with spring boot and 5 seconds with this custom configuration. Maybe jar reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using the server connector instead the server constructor. This works fine with Https.

From

```
Server server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress(jettyHost, 8080));
ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"), 
new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfig));
sslConnector.setPort(jettyPort);
```

To:

```
Server server = new Server();
ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"), 
new HttpConnectionFactory(httpsConfig));
sslConnector.setPort(jettyPort);
sslConnector.setHost(jettyHost);
```